# How to remove item from collection list and catch properly that CollectionChanged event and do something there

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm using observable collection to show list of currently active customers,
I'm showing that list in `DataGrid`, here is how my list looks

```
public ObservableCollection<Company> list = new ObservableCollection<Company>(Controller.SelectAll());
```

What I want to achieve is next: When user selects a company from a DataGrid, there is a button which he can press to delete
that customer/company. And it looks like this (button's event where I'm removing item from observablecollection):

```
private void btnDeleteSelectedCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (dtgMyCustomers.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       Company k = (Company)(dtgMyCustomers.SelectedItem);
       list.Remove(k);
     }
}
```

After this I need to catch CollectionChanged event on Remove action as much as I know?
There I want to remove that item from database, and I thought it might go something like this:

```
public partial class Companies : Window
{


        public ObservableCollection<Company> list = new ObservableCollection<Company>(Controller.SelectAll());

        public Companies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            list.CollectionChanged += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                if (ee.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove
                    && ee.OldItems != null && ee.OldItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    Company removedItem = ee.OldItems[0] as Company;
                    Controller.DeleteFromDatabaseById(removedItem.Id);

                }
            };

        }

        private void btnDeleteSelectedCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dtgMyCustomers.SelectedItem != null)
            {
            Company k = (Company)(dtgMyCustomers.SelectedItem);
            list.Remove(k);
            }
        }

}
```

But unfortunately I did something wrong, because CollectionChange is not firing when I remove item from database in my button click event
hander..

Whatever this is my second time I'm working with ObservableCollections so I'm probably doing this wrong?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Why not removing the item from the database in the same logic where you remove it from the list?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom to be honest I don't know why I am not doing that, probably because I am noob and I thought it should be done like this :D

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Thanks mate, I started learning programming like 1 month ago and I find it pretty difficult because I want to follow right way when I am doing/solving something, I dont want dirty solutions, but there is so many ways and oportunities to solve something so it's hard to determine which way is right and most correct one :/ but I'll keep going, Thanks anyway for your comment :)

Comment: You should have a look at the MVVM pattern when developing WPF applications. There are a lot of good tutorials in the web. Enjoy it and some may forgot it but we all started once ;)

Comment: The event should be fired. Did you really set a breakpoint in the event handler and verified that it doesn't get hit after the Remove method has been called?

Comment: @mm8 Yes I do but I will check it soon one more time..

Comment: @mm8 and is it okay to delete item from database in event where I am removing item from list, or I should do it  as I did in my question? what is more correct way?

Comment: The "correct" way would be to bind the Command property of the Button to an ICommand property of a virw model class and handle the deletion in the latter.

Comment: @mm9 that is "famous" MVVC method that everyone talks about ?

Comment: @billy_56 Yes, that would be MVVM

Comment: @mm8 not yet now I am working on something else I will post question soon cuz I'm stucked for 4 hours allready on button scroller around my grid which contains controls inside.

Comment: @billy_56 If a scroller isn't working it's in 99% a container problem. But can't say anything more without knowing the code. E.g. StackPanel behavior is different then Grid behavior.